# Allow clients to run a server-installed program without being prompted by UAC

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2012-r2, network-share

I'm trying to allow clients to run a program that's installed on our server. I've made a share of the complete installation folder and shared this with all users in our domain. However, when a user tries to run the program on his pc, he is prompted for an administrator password by User Account Control.
How can I make it so that the user isn't prompted for this, without me having to change settings on all (almost 50) client computers?

I know it is possible because it was working like this on our previous server.
- Server: Windows server 2012 R2
- Clients: Windows 7 Pro x64

The program I am trying to run is a translating lexicon.